# How to list 5 largest folders/ files on Linux?

Tags: linux, file-management

I tried to list by the size of the folder using the following command:

```
ls -S | head -1
```

but this only listed folders by size and did not show the size of the folders. Any idea how to see file sizes too?

Comment: Try adding a 'l' `ls -lS`

Comment: Perhaps the `du` command is more what you are looking for.  Try `du -s *`

Comment: I don't know why this question is rated so low.. It's helpful ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Parsing ls is bad](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) - Don't do it ;)

If you're looking at the whole drive, try `du -h / | sort -rh | head -5`

- du -h lists all the files with sizes, in human readable format
- sort -rh reverses the sort, in human readable format
- head -5 returns the top 5 results, (you could also not reverse it but still have to sort it) and use `tail -n 5`
- Instead of `/` you could use any given directory to list only files below that point in your file system.

Comment: Thanks for this answer ;) Saved me a lot of time

Comment: Glad it's been useful to someone, I mainly put it here for self reference.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the much more usable command that lists top largest folders in `/home`.  You can replace `/home` with `/` also.

```
sudo du -a --max-depth=2 --human-readable --time --exclude=.* /home 2>/dev/null | sort --human-numeric-sort --reverse | head -n 15
```

The great thing about above command is that it will only recurse upto 2 levels so you eliminate a lot of noise.